# Cross browser rounded corners (no image)

Tags: cross-browser, rounded-corners

When converting PSD's into HTML or even HTML5 and CSS, how much more difficult is it to round the corners and make those corners consistent across all browsers, especially Internet Explorer?

Assuming the corners were rounded with code, not images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check out [Corner](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/) if you want a JavaScript solution. It's cross platform.

Comment: Looks good as it uses the CS3 properties for browsers that support it and reverts to images for IE.

Comment: CSS3PIE [css3pie.com] as posted below seems the the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

You already accepted but [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) you can just use the `border-radius` property (along with gradients, shadows, and other fun CSS3 features) in IE3. I think it's one of the cleaner ways to approach the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few workarounds for cross browser rounded corners not using Javascript:

> [CSS Rounded Corners In All Browsers](http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers)
>   [An Experiment in Rounded Corners](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/rounded_corners_experiment_ie/)
>   [Rounded corners in CSS (cross browser implementations)](http://journal.mikemamaril.com/2009/05/30/rounded-corners-in-css/)

Using CSS3 for webkit & gecko based browsers, SVG for Opera and VML for IE.
Also you may want to use the well-known [jQuery Corners](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/) if you want it via Javascript.

Comment: I know it's an old thread, but just so you know - the first and the last links rely on using an `.htc` file, which in reality **is** JavaScript - so you can't really say that those two solutions are "..not using Javascript"

Answer (score 1):

With the CS3 `border-radius` property, it's not hard. Some browsers have their own implmentation, like `-moz-border-radius` for firefox and `-webkit-border-radius` for safari and chrome.

But IE still does not support the border-radius, so it's hard to get make it work cross-browser.