# how to make round corner of div

Tags: html, rounded-corners

how to make round corner of `div` in css and I have menu list items

```
 <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">COMPANY</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">SOLUTIONS</a></li>...
```

how to round corners of `li` items

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross browser rounded corners (no image)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814348/cross-browser-rounded-corners-no-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
```

As noted earlier, this will not work in IE. But the newer version of IE will support it I believe  (correct me if I'm wrong, please).

Worst case scenario, IE users will not see rounded corners.
For more about the border radius property [the following is a good article.](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/border-radius/)

Answer (score 2):

Standards-aware solution would be to use `border-radius` of CSS 3.

See http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Comment: @pranay_stacker: It will in future versions.  Meanwhile, it's good enough and more important features can be addressed -- instead of trying to make bad browsers look good.

Comment: Agreed with @Brock. The best practice would mean feature-based filtering instead of browser sniffing. If border-radius is not on, use one of those JS libraries that achieve the same border-radius functionality. IE should not determine the implementation, but suffer of slower performance over its obsolete engine. Unfair to make modern platforms suffer instead.